# Mongoose Not Saving

Tags: javascript, mongoose, save

I see this question has been posted before, but can't seem to relate and find a fix for my situation, I have reduced the code down to basic elements to drill down on the issue, but no solutions yet - it is the first time I've used Mongoose to save records, and not only to query, so I'm sure this is my fault, but what I'm trying is so simple... Please help! Going crazy!

Code:

```
// Constants
var TRUSTED_ORIGIN = "";
var MONGO_SERVER = "mongodb://***.**.**.***/*********";

// Create the database schema
mongoose = require('mongoose');
Schema = mongoose.Schema;
mongoose.connect(MONGO_SERVER);
ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;
//=============================================================
var UsersSchema         = new Schema({
    display_name        : String,
    email               : String,
    mobile              : String,
    activated           : String,
    password            : String
}); 
//=============================================================
//models = require('./models/schemas.js')
var users = mongoose.model('Users',UsersSchema);
//=============================================================

function consoleLogger(msg) {
    console.log("*********************************************************");
    console.log(msg);
}

"use strict";

var myServer = "http://***.***.**.***/";

process.title = '***********';

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Test Components
consoleLogger("Preparing the first test");
var test1 = "";
console.log("Host: "+mongoose.connection.host);
console.log("Port: "+mongoose.connection.port);
var user_value = new users({display_name: 'Jesse',
                            email       : 'jesse@test.com',
                            mobile      : '******',
                            activated   : 'T',
                            password    : 'Test'});
consoleLogger(user_value);

try {
    user_value.save(function(err){
        consoleLogger("Item Saved. Err: "+err);
        users.find({display_name:'jesse'})
            .exec(function(err,data){
                consoleLogger("Item Found")
                test1 = data[0].display_name
                consoleLogger("test1 = "+test1);
            });
    });
}
catch (e) {
    consoleLogger("Failed to save");
}
```

Output:

```
*********************************************************
Preparing the first test
Host: ***.**.**.***
Port: *****
*********************************************************
{ display_name: 'Jesse',
  email: 'jesse@test.com',
  mobile: '*********',
  activated: 'T',
  password: 'Test',
  _id: 54995052c17aa7470bfca9e1 }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, well I have gotten so caught up with similar issues online that I failed to see right past the actual fault of my own being that the IP to use was wrong. Was using the same cloud instance from a past project but since then the IP had been refreshed.

Woops!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking what is in database?
Your query

```
users.find({display_name:'jesse'})
```

does not match data you saved. display_name: '**J**esse',
Could you try with lowercase?

Comment: A valid point, but yes, checked the collections to find it's  nonexistent. Primarily need the verification it got saved by logging "Item Saved", which it is not.